# Image thumbnails slider

Tags: gallery

`js-image-slider.js`

```
var sliderOptions=
{
    sliderId: "slider",
    effect: "13,17,13,13,5",
    effectRandom: true,
    pauseTime: 2600,
    transitionTime: 500,
    slices: 12,
    boxes: 9,
    hoverPause: 1,
    autoAdvance: true,
    captionOpacity: 1,
    captionEffect: "fade",
    thumbnailsWrapperId: "thumbs",
    m: false,
    license: "mylicense"
};

var imageSlider=new mcImgSlider(sliderOptions);
.......
```

`single-photos.php`

```
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>=">
<div id="sliderFrame">
        <div id="slider">
              <?php the_content (); ?>
    </div>          
        <!--thumbnails-->
        <div id="thumbs">
            <div class="thumb"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   <!-- post -->
```

`slider.css`

```
#sliderFrame 
{
    width:680px;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:20px;
    background:#fafafa;
    border:1px solid #666;
    border-radius:1px;
}

#slider {
    width:533px;height:400px;
    background:black url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#slider img {
    position:absolute;
    border:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}

#slider a.imgLink {
    z-index:2;
    display:none;position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
}

div.navBulletsWrapper  {
    display:none;
}

#thumbs 
{
    margin-top:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0;
}
#thumbs .thumb 
{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;zoom:1;
    margin:0 1px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    padding:4px;
    background:black;
}

#thumbs .thumb img{border:1px solid #555; cursor:pointer; width:70px; height:44px; opacity:0.5;filter:alpha(opacity:50);}
#thumbs .thumb img{ opacity:0.6;filter:alpha(opacity:60); } #thumbs .thumb-on img{ opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity:100);}
#thumbs .thumb-on img{border:1px solid #999; opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity:100);}
```

The images :

```
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-1370" title="imagesample1" src="imagesample1.jpg" alt="" width="533" height="400" />
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-1369" title="imagesample2" src="imagesample2.jpg" alt="" width="533" height="400" />
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-1368" title="imagesample3" src="imagesample3.jpg" alt="" width="533" height="400" />
```

For this, the slider didn't work. It's show me only one image, but when i put the images (`<img class="alignnone />`) into the `single-photos.php`, the slider works. What i am doing wrong?

**Update / edit :**
I use another method, without thumbnails.But, why show me only the same image in slider? I have 5.

`header.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#slider").easySlider({
                auto: true, 
                continuous: true
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

`script: easySlider1.7.js`

`single-photos.php`

```
<div id="slider">
 <ul>
   <li>
    <?php the_content (); ?>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

`style.css`

```
#slider
{
    margin-left:85px;
        position:relative;
        text-align:left;
        width:533px;
        background:#fff;        
        margin-bottom:2em;

}

#slider ul, #slider li,
    #slider2 ul, #slider2 li{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        }
    #slider2{margin-top:1em;}
    #slider li, #slider2 li{ 
        width:533px;
        height:400px;
        overflow:hidden; 
        }   
    #prevBtn, #nextBtn,
    #slider1next, #slider1prev{ 
        display:block;
        width:30px;
        height:77px;
        position: relative;
        left:-40px;
        bottom:471px;
        z-index:1000;
        }   
    #nextBtn, #slider1next{ 
         left: 596px;
        }                                                       
    #prevBtn a, #nextBtn a,
    #slider1next a, #slider1prev a{  
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        width:30px;
        height:77px;
        background:url(../images/btn_prev.gif) no-repeat 0 0;   
        }   
    #nextBtn a, #slider1next a{ 
        background:url(../images/btn_next.gif) no-repeat 0 0;   
        }   

    /* numeric controls */  

    ul#controls{
        margin:1em 0;
        padding:0;
        height:28px;    
        }
    ul#controls li{
        margin:0 10px 0 0; 
        padding:0;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        height:28px;
        line-height:28px;
        }
    ul#controls li a{
        float:left;
        height:28px;
        line-height:28px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        background:#DAF3F8;
        color:#555;
        padding:0 10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
    ul#controls li.current a{
        background:#5DC9E1;
        color:#fff;
        }
    ul#controls li a:focus, #prevBtn a:focus, #nextBtn a:focus{outline:none;}
```

Comment: Do you have problem achieving required markup in WP? If not this is likely question for slider script's developer and is not WP specific.

Comment: i check the code again and again. I will be back soon.

Comment: @Rarst with the using of simple jquery I can fix my problem by half, but how can i integrate the thumbnails?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Please update your question with what you are trying to achieve with thumbnails and what part of that you have trouble with.

Comment: even now the problem remains. Did I make a mistake in `single-photos.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with `cycle.js`

`header.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        pause: 1,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next'
        });
    });
    </script>
```

`single-photos.php`

```
<div id="slideshowContainer">
<div class="slideshow"> <?php the_content (); ?> </div>
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="prev"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li id="next"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```